# If Wall Street (in Bryce Canyon) is closed, can I still hike Queens Garden & Navajo Combination?

Tags: usa, hiking, national-parks, utah, closures

[This page](https://www.nps.gov/brca/planyourvisit/conditions.htm) says:

> **Wall Street** and the Rim Trail from Bryce Point to Inspiration Point have closed for the winter season. All other front country trails remain open. Fairyland Point Road and Paria View Roads have closed to allow for skiing and other winter activities.

The [description of Queens Garden & Navajo Combination](https://www.nps.gov/brca/planyourvisit/qgnavajocombo.htm) says:

> ... Continue straight ahead into the **Wall Street** half of the Navajo Loop which will return you back up to Sunset Point ...

Does the closure of Wall Street mean that one cannot hike Queens Garden & Navajo Combination?

Comment: It does appear you can't do that exact hike, but it looks from [the map](https://www.nps.gov/brca/planyourvisit/maps.htm) like you could bypass the closed Wall Street section by taking the other half of the Navajo Loop trail (via Two Bridges) up to Sunset Point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that a small part (at one end) of the Navajo loop trail is closed.

See the park map ([pdf link](https://www.nps.gov/brca/planyourvisit/upload/2018-Bryce-Canyon-Guide-2.pdf)). The map at the right hand side (Bryce Ampitheatre enlarged) gives you the relevant information. Wall street is shown highlighted in orange, which is marked as "summer use only". The rest of the trail is still open, so you could start at Sunrise Point, go down the Queen's Garden Trail, and then turn right at the crossroads to go up the Two Bridges part of the Navajo Loop, to Sunset Point.